# Stablecoin smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, usdt, stablecoins

Drop in smart contract links for ERC-20 stablecoin.
There is no list defined anywhere.
There should be easy to understand resources in one place for new lerners.
what should be the best boilerplate?

Comment: You can find source codes for most projects in Etherscan or Github.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different techniques to ensure a stablecoin maintains its value, so it's not clear if you're looking for a specific type (such as algorithmic stable coins like OHM and DAI) or something else.

I believe USDC/USDT are just fiat backed ERC20s, so it's not necessarily interesting to look at their contract vs. another ERC20. (Here's USDC for reference https://polygonscan.com/address/0xdd9185db084f5c4fff3b4f70e7ba62123b812226#code)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a source for you, however I can write some simple code that'll work as a stablecoin for Ethereum (aka each "MS" token is pegged 1 to 1 with the value of Ethereum). You can then use this reference to create your own by replacing parts of the code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyStablecoin is ERC20 {
  constructor() ERC20("MyStablecoin", "MS") {}

  function getStablecoin() public payable {
    _mint(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }

  function exchangeForEther(uint256 _amount) public {
    _burn(msg.sender, _amount);
    (bool success,) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: _amount}("");
    require(success);
  } 
}
```

I hope this helped